# Understanding the error term in the Siegel‒Walfisz theorem

Tags: calculus, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory

I'd like to inquire as to the nature of the error term in the Siegel‒Walfisz theorem. I understand that it takes the form
$$
O\left( x \exp\left( -C \sqrt{\ln x} \right) \right).
$$

Yet this function is not one of those that one studied in one's first term calculus course and knows everything about. (For instance, a version of the prime number theorem gives an error term of $x/(\ln x)^2$, which is a function that seems more familiar.)

My question is thus: How fast does the error term in the Siegel‒Walfisz theorem grow? How does it compare to better known error terms? (I'd be particularly interested in the error term $x/(\ln x)^2$.)

For instance, writing
$$
x \exp\left( -C \sqrt{\ln x} \right) = \frac{x}{x^{C/\sqrt{\ln x}}},
$$
we find that it eventually supersedes $x^\alpha$ for any $\alpha < 1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compare to $\frac{x}{(\ln x)^2}$ it is helpful to write $(\ln x)^2$ as an exponential. Namely $(\ln x)^2 = \exp( \ln  \ln x)^2 = \exp(2 \ln  \ln x) $.

So in the one you divide by $\exp(C \sqrt{\ln x}) $ and in the other by $\exp(2 \ln  \ln x)$. Now $\sqrt{\ln x}$ grows much faster than $2 \ln  \ln x$, and thus you error-term is smaller (as you divide by something larger).

More generally, the error term is better than $\frac{x}{(\ln x)^k}$ for any positive integer $k$.

So the short is,  better than $\frac{x}{(\ln x)^k}$ for any $k \ge 1$ yet worse than $x^{\alpha}$ for $\alpha \lt 1$, as you said.

It is also worse than $x\exp (-C (\ln x)^{\beta}) $ for $1/2 < \beta <1$ (and better for $\beta <1/2$).

Comment: Could you elaborate on what happens if in the very last line, the logarithm is replaced by a double logarithm?

Comment: That'd be worse than $x / \ln x $ as $(\ln \ln x)^b$ would be smaller than $\ln \ln x$ (at least when $b$ is less than $1$ which is what I meant to impose).

Comment: I think that's a $\beta$ and not a $b$. But thank you very much indeed. Gladly, I just found my brain somewhere, so that it was not entirely necessary...